# Cursor returns with fetch() but not run() on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have this python code for app engine:

```
def queryArticles(status=1, limit=10, **offset):
    query = Article.all().filter('status =', status).order('-modified')
    articles = query.fetch(limit=limit, **offset)
    cursor = query.cursor()
    return articles, cursor
```

If I use fetch() cursor returns, but in case run() is used I get empty string for cursor. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `run()` method merely sets up the conditions required to run the query (and in production, starts the RPC call in the background). In order for your query to have any knowledge of data (cursors or otherwise), you need to fetch the results by exhausting the query.

```
>>> query = Model.all()
>>> query_iterator = query.run(limit=5)
>>> query.cursor()
''
>>> list(query_iterator) # Exhaust iterator
[<db.Model instance at 0x...>, ...]
>>> query.cursor()
'E-ABAIICG2oMYXByaWdvbmluamE0cgsLEgVNb2RlbBgKDBQ='
```

Answer (score 1):

`Query.run()` (or simply iterating over `Query`'s instance) returns an iterator. At the time you getting the query's cursor it hasn't even started fetching anything. I guess, in your case — as you going to use cursors — `fetch()` would be just fine.

In case you really need it, this should do the trick:

```
def queryArticles(status=1, limit=10, **offset):
    query = Article.all().filter('status =', status).order('-modified')
    articles = query.run(limit=limit, batch_size=limit, **offset)
    articles = articles.next()
    cursor = query.cursor()
    return articles, cursor
```

Comment: Thank you, Igor! fetch() is good for me, as articles then go to jinja for output. But because I like to understand what I write, I was interested in the difference between fetch() and run(). And GAE docs only say that fetch() is a wrapper around run()